# How to put laravel components within separate folders

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

When I make new component I would like to have base component like Modal within root directory as it is made:

```
app/View/Components/Modal.php
```

And then I would like to have something like

```
app/View/Components/Modals/Login.php
app/View/Components/Modals/Register.php
app/View/Components/Modals/ResetPassword.php
```

How could I use/call these components like ones from root folder? (Components as root folder)

`<x-modal></x-modal>` - Works fine

But `<x-login></x-login>` or `<x-modals-login></x-modals-login>` doesn't work. Is there something that can work like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/blade#displaying-components) explains this:

> If the component class is nested deeper within the `App\View\Components` directory, you may use the . character to indicate directory nesting. For example, if we assume a component is located at `App\View\Components\Inputs\Button.php`, we may render it like so:

```
<x-inputs.button/>
```

So in your case, this would be:

```
<x-modals.login>
```